# Android - Reject null input problem

Tags: android, validation, input, filter, mask

I am currently trying to get my code to reject a null (empty) input, every time I enter nothing for values it crashes, however telling it to reject "0" worked (as seen in the else if part of the code).

```
boolean check_input1 = Add.this.input.getText().toString().equals(null);
        boolean check_input2 = Add.this.input2.getText().toString().equals(null);
        boolean check_input3 = Add.this.input3.getText().toString().equals(null);

        float pricecheck_input2 = Float.valueOf(Add.this.input2.getText().toString().trim()).floatValue();
        float pricecheck_input3 = Float.valueOf(Add.this.input3.getText().toString().trim()).floatValue();

        if (check_input1 == true | check_input2 == true | check_input3 == true) {
       // prepare the alert box
               AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add.this);

               // set the message to display
               alertbox.setMessage("No fields may be blank");

               alertbox.show();
        }
        else if (pricecheck_input2 == 0 | pricecheck_input3 == 0) {
         // prepare the alert box
               AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add.this);

               // set the message to display
               alertbox.setMessage("Prices must be greater than 0");

               alertbox.show();
        }
        else {
         new InsertDataTask().execute(Add.this.input.getText().toString(), Float.toString(abv_ppl_calculation), Add.this.input3.getText().toString());
        }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace of your crash using logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to examine the logic for your null check. You have:

```
boolean check_input1 = Add.this.input.getText().toString().equals(null);
```

The question is how would a `toString()` to result in `null`? Your code is on the right track since a little digging shows that `.getText()` will never return `null` (it's always a `CharSequence`). The right side of your check should instead check for the empty string. E.g.:

```
boolean check_input1 = Add.this.input.getText().toString().equals("");
```

Comment: What value does `Add.this.input.getText().toString()` return when there's no input if it's not the empty string?

Comment: Outputted to an alert box, no output, seems blank. By changing from | to || the first box now rejects a blank input, others still crash even though they have the same code.

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint on that line (the setting of `check_input1`) and step through the execution to ensure that the boolean flags are getting set the way that you intend (which they would not have been with your original check). I'm not sure which of the bitwise ORs (`|`) you changed to a logical OR (`||`) but in the code you have above, I'm not sure how that *could* make a difference (though you should be using logical ORs for all your checks above - bitwise ORs are rarely needed or wanted).

Comment: Ok I got a fatal exception and it said: "java.lang.NumberFormatException", I think it might be because first were characters and the other two were numbers.

Comment: I have the first box set to normal input then in XML I made it so only number input IME came up.

Comment: Tried them all individually, first one works, second two don't, tried even removing the IME thing, still didn't work :/

Comment: Error that gets thrown if 2/3 are left empty or all are: http://pastebin.com/YEDYqy8z

Comment: Seems the floats are causing it.

Comment: Fixed. Changed price_checks to booleans like check_inputs. Turns out they tried to convert string->number even though there was no value, which caused the error so I encased all other floats in if statements making sure it checked the inputs had a value before conversion.

Comment: @user57820 Sorry I wasn't around to help, but I'm glad to hear you figured it out - properly validating inputs is a skill worth learning well.